# Entity Framework (5) View parameters passed to generated SQL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How do I view the parameters (Bind Variables) passed to the generated SQL command created by Entity Framework (V5)?

```
public IEnumerable<SearchItem> Search(string searchTerm)
{
    return DbSet.Where(p => p.ItemId.Contains(searchTerm)).ToList();
}
```

The code above generated the following SQL and includes the bind variable `__linq__0`

```
SELECT 
     "Extent1"."ITEM" AS "ITEM", 
FROM "TableName" "Extent1"
WHERE UPPER("Extent1"."ITEM") LIKE :p__linq__0
```

How do I debug and view the value of this bind variable when debugging?
I have seen answers which suggested enabling tracing, but there must be a way of checking these values in the Visual Studio debugger.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Entity Framework 6 you could use the Interception/SQL Logging

Here is an example of the link posted below

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    var blog = context.Blogs.First(b => b.Title == "One Unicorn"); 

    blog.Posts.First().Title = "Green Eggs and Ham"; 

    blog.Posts.Add(new Post { Title = "I do not like them!" }); 

    context.SaveChangesAsync().Wait(); 
}
This will generate the following output:

SELECT TOP (1)
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (N'One Unicorn' = [Extent1].[Title]) AND ([Extent1].[Title] IS NOT NULL)
-- Executing at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 4 ms with result: SqlDataReader

SELECT
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
    [Extent1].[BlogId] AS [BlogId]
    FROM [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[BlogId] = @EntityKeyValue1
-- EntityKeyValue1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader

UPDATE [dbo].[Posts]
SET [Title] = @0
WHERE ([Id] = @1)
-- @0: 'Green Eggs and Ham' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing asynchronously at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 12 ms with result: 1

INSERT [dbo].[Posts]([Title], [BlogId])
VALUES (@0, @1)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Posts]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
-- @0: 'I do not like them!' (Type = String, Size = -1)
-- @1: '1' (Type = Int32)
-- Executing asynchronously at 10/8/2013 10:55:41 AM -07:00
-- Completed in 2 ms with result: SqlDataReader
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/dn469464

Comment: Thank you but I'm using Entity Framework 5, sorry. I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You need access to underline command, connection object, Which you can have by downloading EF sourcecode. EF wraps every thing for you.    [EF Codebase](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look into this if there is no other alternative.